# Getting a serial number from shared table

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, concurrency

I have a table that keeps track of a global serial number shared between several tables. This is not the PK or unique id for each table. It is like a case identifier. Every time users create a new entity we need to give them a unique serial number from this row. My worries is what happens if 2 users hit the method for incrementing this counter at the exact same time. Would this solution be enough?

Also this code would be run from 2 servers using the same database.

```
public string GetIdentifier()
{
    int retries = 0;
    bool success = false;

    string newId;

    do
    {
        try
        {
            var tracker = Trackers.Find(1);
            newId = tracker.Increment();
            SaveChanges();
            success = true;

        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            if (++retries == 5)
                throw;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //do some logging
            throw;
        }

    } while (!success);

    return newId;
}
```

Comment: Which language is this? C#? Please add the suitable tag.

Comment: My first guess: Let the database handle this for you. Databases are usually designed for concurrency and are pretty good in such tasks. Do you have some kind of auto increment columns?

Comment: This used to be implemented as a database trigger but I try to make it without triggers (and stored procedures)

Comment: I'm no C# developer, and concurrent and transactional questions are beyond the scope of an code review from my point of view. One requirement of this StackExchange is "working code".  Do verify if your code is working, you need to write high concurrent tests and understand every bit of code between you snipped and your database.

Comment: Your identity is a string. Why don't you use guids?

Comment: @GertArnold It is an identifier for the end user, need to be easy to tell other people.

Comment: Can you add some more code? What `Tracker` is? What `Tracker.Increment()` does? Where/how you open the DB connection? Which are the concurrency settings for your table/db? Your code, as-is, may be somehow reviewed but I suppose that we may do a slightly better job with much more context.

Comment: I've rolled your changes back, since they invalidate the reviews. [What you may and may not do after receiving answers](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765).

Answer (score 1):

You propably won't ever get the effect that 2 people create the same unique identifier at the same time. Still, it could possibly happen, most databases will handle this. If you create your db with unique values only in your table, it will automatically give you an error when 2 values are identic.

Comment: Lets say the table holds the value 4. Then If two processes hit the table at the same time and gets 4 add +1 and try to update the table. The first process that finishes will update the table to 5 and return 5. The last process will find out is hat dirty data and should not return 5. Instead it should re-read the data , add 1, update table and return 6. I dont think that is done "automatically"

Comment: OP worries about 2 processes hitting the same time creating a duplicate value wich is not hte case. Like you mentioned it will increase the counter and 2 new values are created, so it kinda handles this automatically, because the db does not allow to run 2 processes at the same time.

Comment: @Thomas process A read current value (4), process B read current value (4). They're running sequentially (not at the _same time_). Now process A increment the value to 5 and store the new value. Also process B is doing the same. Again SEQUENTIALLY. Both processes have the value 5 (and this is wrong). DB _helps_ you only if table is fully locked (and from OP code I assume this is the case).

Comment: @Jepzen A and B try to store value 4. A succeeds. B fails because the value is defined as unique and 4 already exists. B's thread catches the error, increments the value to 5, retries the save. This is such a **fringe** case for concurrency that the slightly inefficient algorithm is negligible due to it hardly occurring in the first place. If you want unique values in the DB, you should configure the DB column to only allow unique values. If you don't, you're making it possible for your business rules to be violated.

Comment: @Jepzen: In short, you're wrongly equating a `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` to be equivalent to **storing the same value twice**, which is not necessarily the case. E.g. no such exception is encountered if two concurrent threads have a _slight_ time difference between them, yet those threads may still have been saving the same value to the DB. [Here's a link with an answer that relates to handling unique constraint violations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31515776/how-can-i-catch-uniquekey-violation-exceptions-with-ef6-and-sql-server) (look for SQL exception number **2627** in the code)

Comment: @Flater we do not see full code then we can just guess but OP has a table with a single row made of a single column, where it stores the latest used serial number. You set the same value twice? Good, nothing _bad_ will happen and you'll get two serial number with the same value. **OP is right** about DbUpdateConcurrencyException, it's the one he may get while updating the same row concurrently.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti He doesn't need the scalar table. He needs to enforce a unique constraint on his db column with the ID (of the objects, not the scalar counter)

Comment: @Flater we're _guessing_ little bit too much about OP scenario. We do not know if this _number_ will ever be a PK in any other table. It may even be a PK but it has to be unique across multiple tables (think, just for example, about an Issue Tracker DB where Bugs and New Features are in separate tables but their ID is unique). Yes, you _may_ have a table of auto-generated IDs but...do you really want to waste that much space (and, worse, embrace such _hacky_ design) for something you can do with 1 line of SQL code?!

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti: You can enforce a [UNIQUE constraint](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp) **without** requiring the column to be a PK, FK or autogenerated value. I am not talking about a table of autogenerated IDs, and I have no idea how that would even work. I'd like to see your reasoning for considering the UNIQUE constraint a hacky solution, its purpose is exactly what the OP wants: to prevent duplicate values from being saved to the table.

Comment: Yes i do only have a single row with a forced PK

Comment: @Flater I'm talking about PK just for simplicity but it doesn't matter. The point is that you may well have an unique constraint but it does not solve the _problem_ (re-read examples from my previous comment). An autogenerated ID...yes (but OP has a complex string, not a sequence number) however also in that case you need to read back the value. Why this useless complexity? Don't you feel that's hacky?! Query for latest inserted value, add 1, fill the record, try to save, repeat from point 1. DBE has features for this, just use them (not a problem for 1 hit/sec but not good for 1M hit/min)

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a flag to exit the loop when you can simply `return` from function. Also the retry counter may be simplified with a simple `for`.

To put everything together:

```
for (int i=0; i <= MaximumNumberOfRetries; ++i)
{
    try
    {
        var tracker = Trackers.Find(1);
        var newId = tracker.Increment();

        SaveChanges();
        return newId;
    }
    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(GetRandomDelay());
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        //do some logging
        throw;
    }
}
```

I Introduced a `GetRandomDelay()` function, in the (maybe rare) case that three threads/processes/servers are processing a batch of insertions then it's better to de-synchronize them (otherwise the one that will first wait will maybe wait until all the others finished).

---

What you're currently doing is something like this:

```sql
UPDATE Trackers
SET SerialNumber = @NewValue
WHERE SerialNumber = @OldValue
```

It's what EF does in your case and it works because you're updating the field to `@NewValue` only if the existing value is what you expected `@OldValue` (what you read). If *someone* else was updating the DB then value changed and you should retry (just check the number of *affected rows* as result of this command, EF throws `DbUpdateConcurrencyException`).

There is, however, another easier way which is *atomic* on the DB and it will take care of concurrency for you (because of the write lock acquired on the table when writing):

```sql
UPDATE Trackers
SET SerialNumber = SerialNumber + 1
OUTPUT INSERTED.SerialNumber
```

In this case result of your query is the new serial number to use. Note that you have to write some SQL code (or a stored procedure) for this, it's not something you can (AFAIK) do directly from EF but using `Database.SqlQuery()`.